# Is it possible to change the title bar of Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have written a plugin for Jmeter. I am wondering if I can display the version of the plugin in the title bar of Jmeter. I am hoping to do this without modifying the Jmeter code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible without changing code base.
It is done in:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/gui/MainFrame.java

Why do you want to do this ?